# create contact bound of account in CRM C#

Tags: c#, sdk, dynamics-crm, crm

I don't know how I can create a contact bound to an account. I have a csv file with an account and a contact, and I would like to import this data into my CRM. This is my code to add an account into CRM:

```
#region Column One Mappings
// Create a column mapping for a 'text' type field. Ajouter un Compte
ColumnMapping colMapping1 = new ColumnMapping()
{
    // Set source properties.
    SourceAttributeName = "my_new_accounts",
    SourceEntityName = "Account_1",

    // Set target properties.
    TargetAttributeName = "name",
    TargetEntityName = Account.EntityLogicalName,

    // Relate this column mapping with the data map.
    ImportMapId = new EntityReference(ImportMap.EntityLogicalName, importMapId),

    // Force this column to be processed.
    ProcessCode = new OptionSetValue((int)ColumnMappingProcessCode.Process)
};

// Create the mapping.
Guid colMappingId1 = _serviceProxy.Create(colMapping1);
#endregion
```

I would like to create many contacts bound to one account.

Answer (score 0):

The sample code you used is from [CRM SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh547396.aspx), the same sample having code for mapping the Parent Account lookup mapping also.

```
 // Create a lookup mapping to the parent account.  
        LookUpMapping parentLookupMapping = new LookUpMapping().........
```

See this code block, read comments, implement it based on your need.

If you are just experimenting this approach, go ahead. Or you can simply import using OOB data import wizard.